# Android: Find location from location name. Is Android's geocoder the correct way?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

I am trying to build a location based application which shows google map and allows the user to search a location by writing an address (as google maps does).

I have been trying to use android's geocoder to do this, and it finds some addresses. However, one of the first addresses that i tried (vaasankatu, helsinki, finland), it didn't find when I searched by street name (vaasankatu). Also one other street name that I have tried does not return any results. If I add the city (helsinki), or the country (finland) after the street name, then geocoder finds addresses.

Google maps web app and android app find the addresses without any problem just by searching by the street name. I am wondering whether I could somehow make geocoder to return the address when it is searched by the street name? I could of course try to find out the current city with the geocoder and attach it after the query, but this seems a bit like a hack, is there a better way?

I am also a bit worried about the [geocoder documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html), which says:

> "The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in
>   the core android framework. The Geocoder query methods will return an
>   empty list if there no backend service in the platform. Use the
>   isPresent() method to determine whether a Geocoder implementation
>   exists."

I don't quite understand what that means.. So is there a big portion of phones that don't support geocoder? The text seems to suggest there might be, but why would there be such an api then at all..? Should I use another api alltogether? Is, for example [Google geocoding api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) for web services usually used? Or places api?

Comment: " I could of course try to find out the current city with the geocoder and attach it after the query, but this seems a bit like a hack" Why does this seem like a hack? The current city seems like a reasonable default to me.

Comment: I think using the current city has two downsides. First if the user wants the street of the neighboring city s/he won't find it (I don't know a way to get the close by cities). Secondly I'm not sure if geocoder can always provide the current city. However this made me think that maybe the other method of geocoder would work better. The method takes a bounding box, so I could start searching the close by places and enlarge the box giving suggestions to the user. I will try this when I have time. Thanks for the comment btw, the bounding box method wouldn't necessarily have occurred me otherwise.

Comment: That sounds like an even better idea. In the case of a "city" which occupies a small geographical region, the bound box will give other locations which are nearby, but not in the city. Conversely, in a geographically large city, a bounding box will give results which are actually near the city...wait a minute, maybe a bounding **circle** would be better (and maybe even easier to calculate with?)

Comment: Did you managed to implement this @Pete? Because I am trying to do it and can't find how to solve this problem.

Comment: I had some problem with the bounding box, don't remember what the problem was though. In the end I just added the country/city at the end of the query. I think like that it works quite well.